# Spark alternative for Redshift REGEXP_SUBSTR function

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, apache-spark-sql

Trying to convert part of Redshift query into SparkSQL or some combo of SQL and UDF:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(referrer, '[^/]+\\.[^/:]+') as referrer_domain,
```

Tried using `regexp_extract(referrer, '[^/]+\\.[^/:]+', 1)`, but that doesn’t seem to work the same way and returns results inconsistently.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: could you try regexp_replace(referrer, '[^/]+\\.[^/:]+', $1)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use regexp_extract in spark sql, something like this -

```
regexp_extract(columnName, '(YourRegex)', 1) as aliasName
```

Note the () around regex to capture the group. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please see original question - what you posted is the same code provided different/inconsistent results.

Comment: Nope. Circular brackets are missing from the code you are talking about.

Comment: It would also help if you provide an example input and expected output. That way, solution provider can confirm more. Thanks.

Comment: What to do for the nth occurrence and starting index of the string which are there as parameters in REGEXP_SUBSTR
REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, pattern [, start_position [, nth_appearance [, match_parameter [, sub_expression ] ] ] ] )